# Can't interact with ghost keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm animating an object, as well as its textures, and for some reason, there are some keyframes visible in the timeline that I can't interact with.

I've tried selecting all channels, moving, deleting, restarting Blender, and all that, but nothing helps

[My blend file](https://workupload.com/file/SpBzzgTpcAC)

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

[image: Animation of ghost keyframes not moving]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Remove all the useless elements

Comment: Hey, how can I share my file?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or another platform like workupload

Comment: Here's a link to the file:
https://workupload.com/file/SpBzzgTpcAC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your material in the *Shader Editor*, these keyframes belong to this node, select it and you'll be able to move or remove them:

[image]

If you open the *Dope Sheet* and disable the *Only Show Selected* option, you won't have to select the node, you'll see the shader name in the track list on the left:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
But how were you able to figure out which node ha d the problem?
Did you have to check each node one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can easily spot the node, but if you select all the nodes you'll see Mix Shader appear as a track on the left panel

Comment: Or as in my Edit, disable the Only Show Selected option in the Dope Sheet

Comment: Alright, thanks for the helpful tips